# Sacar el Max con valores iguales y fechas diferentes

Tags: sql-server

Tengo el siguiente escenario: Una tabla con 3 campos :1-Código 2-Fecha 3-DiasAtrasos

```
Código    Fecha            DiasAtrasos
100         22/4/2020     20
100         22/5/2020     20
200         22/6/2020     20
200         22/7/2020     10
```

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

Sacar los códigos con el Max DiasAtrasos y la fecha correspondiente al Max DiasAtrasos.  como puedo hacer eso en caso de que un codigo tenga en diferentes fecha la misma cantidad de dias de atrasos ?

Al final lo que quiero es hacer esto:

```
Código    Fecha            DiasAtrasos
100         22/5/2020     20
200         22/6/2020     20
```

Sacar el Max DiasAtrasos y la fecha a la cual corresponde. se me complica mucho por que en diferentes fechas puedo tener la misma cantidad de días de atrasos.

Comment: Bienvenido alejandro beras a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿Que versión de SQL estás usando?

Comment: Sql Server 2014

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```
; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Código,
           Fecha,
           DiasAtrasos,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Código ORDER BY DiasAtrasos DESC, Fecha) as rn
       FROM Tabla
)
SELECT Código,
       Fecha,
       DiasAtrasos
       FROM CTE
       WHERE rn = 1
```

La idea es:

- Usamos un [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para generar un numerador por `Código` y ordenado por `DiasAtrasos` en orden descendente y la fecha, esa es la idea del `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Código ORDER BY DiasAtrasos DESC, Fecha)`
- Consultamos el [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para quedarnos solo con las primeras filas de cada grupo

Comment: Gracias Patricio, esta excelente tu ejemplo. Te lo agradezco

Comment: Estimado Patricio al aplicar el ejemplo me di cuenta que me esta arrojando registros diferentes a lo esperando no me esta arrojando El Max dia de atrasos